# jQuery/Javascript: Google Maps: How to toggle multiple pins on a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have a database of locations which I want to be able to print on a map.  Ideally there should be one map with multiple pins for each location you have toggled on.  So click a button for location X and it shows up on the map.  Click the button for location Y and it shows up *on the same map*.  Click X again and it *hides* from the map.

Currently I have it so I click on X and the map gets redrawn centered around point X.

Here is the HTML for each button:

```
<input type='button' data-lat='38.89864400' data-long='-77.05283400'
              data-when='20 Aug at 2:00am' value='Location X' class='click' />
```

The jQuery I'm using is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(

    function initialize() {

        jQuery("input.click").click(function() {
            showOnMap(jQuery(this).data('lat'), jQuery(this).data('long'), jQuery(this).data('when'));
        });
    }
);

function showOnMap(lat, long, message) {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: message
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', showOnMap);
}
```

Is there an easy way to switch from what I have to what I want?  I've searched for a while but no one seems to be asking this use case in a browser, just Android (which I'm not doing).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) on how to hide/show markers. In short, a marker is:

- hidden by setting its map to `null`
- showed by setting its map to `map`

To do so, you will need to access each marker individually. If you have a definite number of locations, it can be done by naming them with different names (eg `var markerLocationX`, `var markerLocationY`, etc). Otherwise, the markers need to be stored in an array.

Supposing you have a definite number of known locations to toggle the markers, your javascript code may look like this:

```
function toggleMarker(markerName) {
  if (markerName.getMap() == null) {
    markerName.setMap(map);
  } else {
    markerName.setMap(null);
  }
}
```